# CSS: Move Icon Closer to Overflowed Text

Tags: html, css

I would like to move the icon closer to the text making them both centered in the container, but the text took up all the remaining space of the container.

Here's the code:

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 108px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
}

i {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolorsit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span>
  <i class="material-icons">face</i>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle to playaround: https://jsfiddle.net/ar71y0n6/

Here's how the code currently works.

[image: sample overflowed text with icon]

Here's the expected output:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Not sure how it should look like, could you add the resulting image? Maybe edit it with photoshop?

Comment: Hi @Ellie, I have updated the question with the expected output.

Comment: Hi @Nickr, try addigng a background color to span then you will see that span is taking that much of space because the text need it then add width to span I have updated the codepen link :- https://codepen.io/shahilparichay/pen/GRvdVqE

Comment: Hi @SHAHILMISHRA, thank you for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to SHAHIL MASHIRA, for the idea of giving the span a width.

Here's the resolution code:

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 108px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 95px;
}

i {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

I used max-width so that the short texts aren't affected.

Here's the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ar71y0n6/1/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adjust setting for yourself that i given i hope it will work

```css
i {
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  */Turn into px if percentage dont work*/ top: 30%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can defined `max-width: 70%` or as your need in `span` tag. In my snippet you can show red border for how much space covering by `span` tag after defined `max-width`.
*I hope below snippet will help you a lot.*

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.border{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red;
}
.container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 108px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.container-w200{width: 200px;}
.container-w300{width: 300px;}
span {
    max-width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}
i {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolorsit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span>
    <i class="material-icons">face</i>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <span class="border">Lorem ipsum</span>
    <i class="material-icons border">face</i>
</div>

<div class="container container-w200">
    <span class="border">Lorem ipsum dol orsit amet, conse ctetur adip iscing</span>
    <i class="material-icons border">face</i>
</div>

<div class="container container-w300">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolorsit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span>
    <i class="material-icons">face</i>
</div>

<div class="container container-w300">
    <span class="border">Lorem ipsum</span>
    <i class="material-icons border">face</i>
</div>
```